# MySql - Several tables with marginally different columns

Tags: mysql, insert

I have several tables with marginally different columns. For simplicity say I have two tables:

mytable1:

```
UserId (int) (primary key)
Save (blob)
```

mytable2:

```
UserId (int) (primary key)
Save (blob)
Save2 (blob)
```

I am then writing a function in php which universally INSERTS a new row. $db is the database connection, $saveTable will be "mytable1" or "mytable2" and the $UserId will be a number like 2, 3 etc.

```
function InsertSaveTable($db, $saveTable, $UserId)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO " . $saveTable . " (UserId, Save, Save2) VALUES (:UserId, '', '')");
    $stmt->execute(array(':UserId' => $UserId));
    $stmt->closeCursor(); // mysql_free_result equivalent
}
```

However, there is a problem with this function. Namely, the column Save2 only exists in mytable2. I only want to set Save2 to '' only when the column exists. I want to do this in the MYSQL rather than the php. (I want to do it in MYSQL looking at the table at the point of insert, as there are a lot more tables than just mytable1 and mytable2, and there will be a lot more added later on.)

The tables are a lot larger, about 50% the same, with only a few differences such as the existence or not of Save2. I do not want to have tables with loads of unused columns.

Is there a way of writing a general mysql INSERT statement for all these tables, only setting Save2 to '' when necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no there is not.

You have to check what columns $saveTable has one way or another before inserting.

Personally, if possible, I would look into creating a stored procedure in mysql that does the checking and inserts the relevant values. That way you can keep your php simple and just pass all variables to the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks @Nikoline Hejbøl . I had not heard of stroed proceedures. They look very nice, and perfect for what I am trying to do.